# How to write on a null cell using java?

Tags: java, excel, report, apache-poi

I am currently doing a program in Java that will run several tests and generate a report right after in excel. I was able to read and write through excel and the results of **Passed** or **Failed** are displayed in Results column. I was able to write these in excel but by supplying a **default** value on the cell (e.g. default) so the code will just overwrite it. I would like to write a comment on the Comment column, but I do not know how to write in a **null** cell. Here is a screenshot of the report I am generating (the link of the image available) and the code for reading and writing in excel as well.

```
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("ReportExcel.xls");
HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream);
HSSFSheet worksheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);   

fileInput csvInputFile = new fileInput();
String[] sReturnValue = csvInputFile.arrayReturnSingleValue("fileInput.csv");
if (prodnameresult.equals(prodname) ){
    Pass++;
    totalResult++;
    System.out.println ("Testcase1: Branding-Customised Product Name is PASSED");
    //Harold's Input    
        HSSFRow row = worksheet.getRow(1);
        HSSFCell cell = row.getCell((short) 4);
        cell.setCellValue("Passed");
    } 
else{
    Fail++;
    totalResult++;
    System.out.println("Testcase1: Branding-Customised Product Name is FAILED");
    //assertEquals(prodnameresult.equals(prodname), true);
    //Harold's Input
         HSSFRow row = worksheet.getRow(1);
         HSSFCell cell = row.getCell((short) 4);
         cell.setCellValue("Failed");
    }

//Harold's Input
    FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("ReportExcel.xls");
    workbook.write(os);
    os.close();
}
```

Report:

http://i47.tinypic.com/2s1lsfc.png

Comment: Could you instead create a blank cell, for the ones where you want to put a comment but no value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have access to the report, but to answer to your question, if your cell is **null** you should create it and not get it as following:

```
HSSFCell cell = row.getCell((short) 4);
if(cell == null)
   cell = row.createCell((short) 4);
cell.setCellValue("Passed");
```

You should maybe re-apply the Style to the Cell if it had a different one from the row.